RBAC in argocd based on k8s namespaces

Application RBAC¶
The RBAC syntax for Application objects has been changed
from <project>/<application> to <project>/<namespace>/<application> to
accommodate the need to restrict access based on the source namespace
of the Application to be managed.
For backwards compatibility, Applications in the argocd namespace
can still be refered to as <project>/<application> in the RBAC
policy rules.
Wildcards do not make any distinction between project and application
namespaces yet. For example, the following RBAC rule would match any
application belonging to project foo, regardless of the namespace it
is created in:
p, somerole, applications, get, foo/*, allow

If you want to restrict access to be granted only to Applications in
project foo within namespace bar, the rule would need to be
adapted as follows:
p, somerole, applications, get, foo/bar/*, allow


This is the argocd docomentaion for version 2.13.
i have the same version, but no matter how i play it i can't make the namespace to be the deciding factor for permissions. i only can filter by app name or project name.
can you help me underastand what am i missing?
this is my policy:
role:todo, *, *, */monitoring/*, allow.
i want to allow the group todo to be able to see and change only resources in k8s namespace 'monitoring'. but it doesnt work. i get nothing for those users, as i dont have any application with this name.
it interprets it as project-name/application-name
instead of project-name/namespace/application-name  as the documentation shows
